# Directory as command line argument without using full path name in linux

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

How do you -ls another directory's contents from current directory without listing the other directory's full path as command line argument? I also need to sort the contents of the directory by size, and only output the size and name only. For example, I have the following shell script named `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -lS $1 | awk '{print $5, $9}'
```

The -lS lists files by size, and the awk prints only the size and file name as output. The $1 is the command line argument, but right now, it can only take in a directory's full path for this to work. For example, I have a directory whose path is `/accounts/documents/folder/directory1`.

To call this script, I have to type `$ script.sh /accounts/documents/folder/directory1` for this to work. Is there something I can change in my script so that in command line, I only have to type `$ script.sh directory1` for this to work?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: What is the script supposed to do if there's more than one `directory1` on the system? Which one should it use?

Comment: I think I'm just assuming that there is only one directory1, like I said using the full path works, but I was just wondering if it's possible to just use the directory name.

Comment: @kelp99 `script.sh directory1` works if you first `cd /accounts/documents/folder`. Accepting absolute paths and relative paths from the current directory is the way all unix tools and syscalls work. If you want your tool to have the non-standard behavior of searching the filesystem for the given name, you have to code that yourself (perhaps using `find`)

Comment: Searching the entire filesystem for the one directory with that name will be slow.

Comment: Will it always be a subdirectory of `/accounts/documents/folder`? You could put that directory prefix in the script.

Comment: There are three options: list the full path; list a `relative` path using `../../whatever`; create a symlink from the current directory to the target dir and then treat the symlink like a sub-dir.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directory you are looking for is always a subdirectory, the following script should work :

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE  in `find . -name "$1" `
do
    if [ -d $FILE ]
    then
        ls -lS $FILE | awk '{print $5, $9}'
    fi
done
```